# Code completion for Sketchup Ruby API

Tags: ruby, sketchup

Does anyone know of a program that has support for code completion for Sketchup Ruby API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some Ruby IDEs that have code completion:

- JetBrains RubyMine: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/
- NetBeans Ruby plugin: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Ruby

Unfortunately, it looks like you might need to do some work to get the Sketchup API symbols loaded into your IDE of choice. If I come across anything, I'll edit this answer.

You might also try posting to their mailing list to see if they have any ideas: http://groups.google.com/group/google-sketchup-developers

Comment: I have posted a question to the mailing list of group for google sketcup at google. Thanx for recomendation. For Ruby I use Komodo Edit, which I like and is free, but I dont have a extension for Google Sketchup API...

Answer (score 0):

I found a code-completion addon for Notepad++. I added the SketchUp Ruby API methods to the Ruby code completion. Though I think it needs updating to support SU8's methods. I don't remember where I found it, but pretty sure it was somewhere on the SketchUcation forum: http://forums.sketchucation.com/
I'll post back if I find it.